# Avalon Docking with Prism

Tags: wpf, prism, avalondock

Anyone hooked Avalon docking with Prism yet? I mean the Adapter, so that when you register the views with Prism's region, you could write short hand XAML and prism will create the tabs?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

well, I did ended up creating an prism adapter, wasn't too bad, however, I am realizing that I was working with AvalonDock 1.3, and there is a newer 2.0 version created with MVVM in mind.

So my XAML looks like one would expect with prism:

```
<ad:DockingManager prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"/>
```

Once the View is registered with container and added to the "MainRegion" the adapter will create a Avalon DocumentPane with view as DocumentContent

Comment: yes i did, why would I post it here then? it's been working ever since on the app that's been in production for 5+ years now